# Floating leg of a standard swap still has a value at par when we use the OIS as discount factor?

Tags: libor, fix

Does a bond paying floating coupon `LIBOR`, still has the value at par when we use the `OIS` as discount factor?
It seems only when the Identity:
$$B(t,T_2)(1+(T_2-T_1)F(t,T_1,T_2))=B(t,T_1)$$
still holds, the proposition above will be true. Here $B(t,T)$ is the value of zero coupon bond, $F(t,T_1,T_2)$ is the `forward LIBOR.`

In John Hull's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives  9th` `page 205`  ,shows the way to calculate the forward LIBOR implied in `Swap rate` under `OIS discounting.` But it's the case we know $B(t,T_1),$ but don't know $B(t,T_2).$

If we know both $B(t,T_1)$ and $B(t,T_2).$ Can we calculate the forward LIBOR still as above identity?

Denote

$D_{ois}(t):$ the discounted factor of OIS

$B(t,T):$ Bond price

$E_t[]:$ Conditional expectation at time $t$ under OIS-risk neutral measure which makes $D_{ois}(t)B(t,T)$ martingale for all $T.$

Use $N(t) = D_{ois}(t)B(t,T_1)$ as a numeraire to change the measure into OIS $T_1$-forward measure $E^{T_1}_t[]$(simply use expectation represent new measure).

Then
$$ \dfrac{B(t,T)}{B(t,T_1)} = \dfrac{D_{ois}(t)B(t,T)}{D_{ois}(t)B(t,T_1)}$$
should be martingale under $E^{T_1}_t[].$ Then use the definition of the forward LIBOR $F(t, T, T_{1})$ we can prove that
$$\dfrac{1}{D_{ois}(T)}E_{T}\left[D_{ois}(T_1)\Big((T_1-T) \cdot F(T, T, T_{1})+1\Big)\right] = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, the Libor floater is not worth par when discounting at OIS (unless there is no basis between OIS and Libor).

In a dual curve settings discounting is done at $B_{OIS}(t, T)$, whereas the forward libors are computed on the projection curve as $F(t, T_1, T_2) = (B_{libor}(t, T_1)/B_{libor}(t, T_2) - 1)/(T_2 - T_1)$, where $B_{OIS}(t, T)$ is the discount factor on the OIS curve and $B_{libor}(t, T)$ is the discount factor on the libor curve.

Comment: pls see my update, could show me which step is incorrect?

Comment: actually I am not much understand what's the $B_{OIS}$ and $B_{LIBOR}?$ Why is discounted factor not D(t) and B(t,T)is the bond price. As you say, the forward LIBOR $F(t,T,T_1)$ will not change under the OIS discounting?

Comment: @AntoineConze The floater might not be priced to par even if there's no basis, due to holidays/day counts and all the fun stuff..

Comment: @HelinGai if we ignore all  other factors like holidays/day counts, is my deduction correct in my update?